# Layout with unwanted black borders

Tags: android, layout, inflate

In my app I have a `LinearLayout` with a `FrameLayout` inside. Both are setted to `fill_parent`. I'm running my app in full screen mode. But even with theses params the layouts aren't inflated. The `LinearLayout` remains in the center of the screen and around it, is filled with black.
I'll put some code here now:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    if(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation() == 0) {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler = new Handler();
    pictureTime = 0L;
    isRunning = false;

    _camView = new CameraPreview(this);
    ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraFrame)).addView(_camView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraoverlay, null);
    this.addContentView(overlayView,
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

For me it's correct. SO what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your `_camView` to a `FrameLayout`, so how about using:

```
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

instead of the `LinearLayout` version?

If this doesn't work, please post your xml layout.

Comment: It doesn't work. This is my xml file. The main.xml file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/cameraFrame" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
`

Comment: Other advice would be to try using the CameraPreview itself as your content view. Then once that is working, wrap it in a FrameLayout. Once that is working, wrap it in a LinearLayout. To me it looks correct, but with trying different things you might see what the problem is.